# Error message failure in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tools model

```
class Tools < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :description, :image_url      
end
```

When I submit the form without filling in data, I get error messages as `{{attribue}}{{message}}` ? How can I get the current error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed `I18n` gem? if so,

```
gem uninstall I18n
```

This has to solve the issue.